# why should i put sleep function for getting paypal transaction id after a payout request?

Tags: php, paypal

Hope anyone gives answer my question. I am working with PayPal PHP SDK where a user can make a payout. Everything working fine only the problem I am facing is that I am not getting transaction id after a payout. if I do not get a transaction id in response then I will not able to identify last transaction status on IPN listener. Below my well-commented code, you can see what is going wrong.

```
require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';

    // Create a new instance of Payout object
    $payouts = new \PayPal\Api\Payout();


    $senderBatchHeader = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader();
    // ### NOTE:
    // You can prevent duplicate batches from being processed. If you specify a `sender_batch_id` that was used in the last 30 days, the batch will not be processed. For items, you can specify a `sender_item_id`. If the value for the `sender_item_id` is a duplicate of a payout item that was processed in the last 30 days, the item will not be processed.
    // #### Batch Header Instance
    $senderBatchHeader->setSenderBatchId(uniqid())
            ->setEmailSubject("You have a payment");

    // #### Sender Item
    // Please note that if you are using single payout with sync mode, you can only pass one Item in the request
    $senderItem1 = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem();
    $senderItem1->setRecipientType('Email')
            ->setNote('Thanks you  for your paymnet')
            ->setReceiver('shakti.cmexpertise+0522@gmail.com')
            ->setSenderItemId("" . uniqid())
            ->setAmount(new \PayPal\Api\Currency('{
                            "value":"1.0",
                            "currency":"USD"
                        }'));

    $payouts->setSenderBatchHeader($senderBatchHeader)
            ->addItem($senderItem1);


    // For Sample Purposes Only.
    $request = clone $payouts;

    // ### Create Payout
    try {
        $output = $payouts->create(null, $apiContext);

        /* get payout batch id of last payout */
        $payoutBatchId = $output->getBatchHeader()->getPayoutBatchId();

        try {
            /* get last payout status using payoutBatchId */
            $payoutBatch = \PayPal\Api\Payout::get($payoutBatchId, $apiContext);
            $payoutItems = $payoutBatch->getItems();
            /* get payout item id */
            $payoutItemId = $payoutItems[0]->getPayoutItemId();


            // ### Get Payout Item Status
            try {
                /* get payout item status of last payout */
                ## below if i put a sleep function of 30 seconds it will return me transaction id if i remove sleep function it will not give transaction id##
                $output2 = \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem::get($payoutItemId, $apiContext);
                echo $output2;
                die;
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
                ResultPrinter::printError("Get Payout Item Status", "PayoutItem", null, $payoutItemId, $ex);
                exit(1);
            }
            die;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
            //ResultPrinter::printError("Get Payout Batch Status", "PayoutBatch", null, $payoutBatchId, $ex);
            exit(1);
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
        ResultPrinter::printError("Created Batch Payout", "Payout", null, $request, $ex);
        exit(1);
    }     exit(1);
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
        ResultPrinter::printError("Created Batch Payout", "Payout", null, $request, $ex);
        exit(1);
    }
```

What response i get if i put a sleep function before

```
sleep(30);
$output2 = \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem::get($payoutItemId, $apiContext);
echo $output2;
```

The response like this where i get transaction id:

```
{
    "payout_item_id": "QVF223JGF75L4",
    "transaction_id": "5H458734LM705962G",
    "transaction_status": "SUCCESS",
    "payout_item_fee": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "0.25"
    },
    "payout_batch_id": "46G8LEN83TFBQ",
    "payout_item": {
        "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "value": "1.00"
        },
        "note": "Thanks you for your paymnet",
        "receiver": "shakti.cmexpertise+0522@gmail.com",
        "sender_item_id": "5b51cc1fdc599"
    },
    "time_processed": "2018-07-20T11:55:57Z",
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts-item/QVF223JGF75L4",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET",
            "enctype": "application/json"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts/46G8LEN83TFBQ",
            "rel": "batch",
            "method": "GET",
            "enctype": "application/json"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I remove sleep function like this then I have different output.

```
$output2 = \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem::get($payoutItemId, $apiContext);
echo $output2;
```

this above code will not give me transaction id and the response is like below.

```
{
    "payout_item_id": "VWJD9YJC42728",
    "transaction_status": "PENDING",
    "payout_item_fee": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "0.25"
    },
    "payout_batch_id": "3CZ766WZNRVZG",
    "payout_item": {
        "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "value": "1.00"
        },
        "note": "Thanks you for your paymnet",
        "receiver": "shakti.cmexpertise+0522@gmail.com",
        "sender_item_id": "5b51d2493b77b"
    },
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts-item/VWJD9YJC42728",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET",
            "enctype": "application/json"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts/3CZ766WZNRVZG",
            "rel": "batch",
            "method": "GET",
            "enctype": "application/json"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see I did not get any transaction id in the second code. I want to remove the sleep function. and if I remove then how can I make it work. my goal is that I need transaction id in response.

Answer (score 1):

You should repeat your requests while "transaction_status": "PENDING" in response.

```
$response = \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem::get($payoutItemId, $apiContext);

while ($response['transaction_status'] === 'PENDING') {
  $response = \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem::get($payoutItemId, $apiContext);
  sleep(1);  
}
```

Comment: can i call async request in php

Comment: @ShaktiSisodiya , there is no normal way to do it async in PHP.

Comment: is there any another option for paypal payouts. doing in a right way.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is, to use [socket functions](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php).

You can use your script to store Pending payments (by example Redis).
Use socket's function to have PHP daemon that check Pending payments in Database.

It's a way.