# What is process to integrate paypal payout rest API in php

Tags: php, paypal

I am working on PayPal Payout API.i am not getting what exactly process should be for a complete payout payment method.everything is working fine but still there are so many bugs. what I and mobile application developer is doing.

Mobile API calls to the server with an amount so that server side a PayPal SDK has been integrated where I make a call on PayPal and make a transaction.

The problem is that whether a payer email register or not in Paypal it returns status PENDING without any transaction id.

And I have set up an IPN listener on PayPal which makes a call whenever payout status update. but it returns transaction_id and I am not getting transaction id while payout made.

I don't know what I need to do with it. Please if you did not understand you can drop a comment.

I am using the simple code for Payouts.

```
$headers = array(
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization:Bearer '.$accsessToken,
    );


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts?sync_mode=false");
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));



$result = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($result, 1);

$payoutBatchId = $response['batch_header']['payout_batch_id'];




$headers = array(
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization:Bearer '.$accsessToken,
    );

unset($ch);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts/".$payoutBatchId);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($result, 1);

dd($response);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [PHP  Paypal SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK).
There is some easy [examples](https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/).

Hope this help.

Comment: The SDK gives me transaction id after 30 seconds of wait. meanwhile mobile app cant waits for it. there are high chances that user can kill the app from background.i don't want to let mobile application wait. they can't wait for 30 seconds. any other IDEAS ?

Comment: yes Dear you can see my last question you will get a complete idea whats going with my code. the link is [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442497/why-should-i-put-sleep-function-for-getting-paypal-transaction-id-after-a-payout/51442737?noredirect=1#comment89857502_51442737]